# How does Linux portably handle paging hierarchies with different numbers of levels?

Tags: linux

The classical Linux book 'Understanding the Linux kernel' contains this paragraph about the paging model:

> For 32-bit architectures with no Physical Address Extension, two
>   paging levels are sufficient. Linux essentially eliminates the Page
>   Upper Directory and the Page Middle Directory fields by saying that
>   they contain zero bits. However, the positions of the Page Upper
>   Directory and the Page Middle Directory in the sequence of pointers
>   are kept so that the same code can work on 32-bit and 64-bit
>   architectures. **The kernel keeps a position for the Page Upper
>   Directory and the Page Middle Directory by setting the number of
>   entries in them to 1 and mapping these two entries into the proper
>   entry of the Page Global Directory**.

I really cannot comprehend these bold sentences above.